# "Move it away" NPM Error when deploying to Azure

Tags: azure, npm

I keep getting the following error when deploying my Node.js website to Azure.

npm ERR! EEXIST, open 'D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\428e5db9-pm-cache-acorn-1-1-0-package-tgz.lock'
File exists: D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\428e5db9-pm-cache-acorn-1-1-0-package-tgz.lock
Move it away, and try again.

It is an existing site that has been running on Azure for months.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this issue by updating Node to 0.12.2 by adding this setting to my package.json

```
"engines": {"node": "0.12.2"}
```